# MS Access - pass a parameter to SQL statement from the user input in a textbox

Tags: sql, sql-server, forms, ms-access, textbox

I'm new to MS Access. I don't know if it's possible to create a textbox in which the user inserts a string (a name), then this string to be passed automatically in an sql statement like below for the purpose of retrieving data and display it in some textboxes.

```
select field from myTable 
where userName = @combobox.name
```

There are 2 challenges:

- How to pass inside an sql query the value typed by the user in a textbox?
- If there is just one row in the database for a user, then every textbox should be filled with that info from the query (let's say first point has a solution). But what if a user has multiple rows? How do can one display this?

I'm trying to go on this path because I need to avoid subforms and I would like to have a main form in which there is a textbox for the user to insert a name and then several textboxes, each of those textboxes with their own sql statement(because I need different filters) and for them to be able to expand or to somehow display multiple rows if there are multiple records for an user.

Is it possible to do this in a form in access? If yes, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please read this before writing any code.  http://nibblesec.org/files/MSAccessSQLi/MSAccessSQLi.html   and  https://milo2012.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/sql-injection-for-microsoft-access/

Comment: @granadaCoder read it, thank you. What I'm trying to achieve is being used locally and it should be ok. Now I need to figure it out if it's possible and how

Comment: @CM2K don't be too nonchalant about ignoring sql injection. Even if nobody but yourself will ever use this application you should take this as a great opportunity to learn how to prevent it. Once you learn how to use properly parameterized queries it is super easy and you will be rewarded with much better applications.

Comment: @SeanLange I understand, now going back to the question, do you have any solution or insight?

Comment: I can probably help but the question just isn't at all clear to me what you are trying to do. You would create each query with a parameter and use the text property of your textbox as the value.

Comment: If you reference the combo in your query like this ... `WHERE userName = Forms!YourForm!combobox` ... it is a parameter so there is no risk of SQL injection.

Comment: @SeanLange there is a textbox where the user inputs his search. Based on this search there should be 7 frames/tables which each are displaying certain columns from the table. Example: one frame(i'm trying to avoid calling it subform because maybe it can be outputted in some generated textboxes) should do `select equipmentType, dateReceived, dateGivenBack from myTable where name = textbox.value` then another block/frame/subform displaying MobileDevice which should have a query like `select deviceType phoneNumber from myTable where name = textbox.value` and so on

Comment: What I want is something like: use this query and output these 3 columns, then below use a different query and output other couple of columns and so on. All from the same table and all based on the userName

Comment: So what is preventing you from doing that? You have to remember we can't see your screen and have no idea what your project is other than what you tell us. Up to this point all we have is some pretty sparse details on what you are trying to do. It sounds like you just need to create 7 queries all using the same name from the same textbox.

Comment: @SeanLange how does one : `creates 7 queries all using the same name from the same textbox and displays the outcome in 7 textboxes` ? I know how to write the queries, but not how to do the rest

Comment: Since the queries can return more than one row, can you present the results in 7 list boxes instead of 7 text boxes?

Comment: @HansUp yes, that would be also good

Comment: OK.  Add an unbound list box to your form.  Unbound means leave its Control Source property blank.  Use one of your queries as the list box Row Source property.  Does that do what you want?

Comment: @HansUp If I simply write a query in the row source, nothing happens. And how do I bind that to the combobox? like `select field1, field2 from myTable where userName = Forms!YourForm!combobox.value` in case you guys haven't noticed, I am not very advanced into using this. You have to know about a software to be able to ask the right questions

Comment: First, does that `SELECT` query return the data you want?  If so, what happens when you use that query as the list box Row Source, switch to Form View, select a value in the combo, and then press `F5`?

Comment: @HansUp Thanks for the suggestion. the listbox almost works now. In the query I'm selecting 5 columns and the listbox only outputs 1 column. Do you have any idea on how I could display all? And I set up the Bound Column property to 5. Once I will solve this, then I will write an answer for future readers

Comment: Yes, change the *Column Count* property to 5.  You can find that property on the "Format" tab of the list box's property sheet.

Comment: @HansUp got it, Fixed the problem. The listbox suggestion was what I needed, please write a small answer and I will use that as accepted. Maybe future readers will also be confused at first on what to use like me. I could also write a small tutorial but I feel like the credit should go to you

Answer (score 0):

```
DIM strSQL as String

strSQL = "SELECT [mytable].[field] " _ 
& "FROM [myTable] " _ 
& "WHERE [MyTable].[userNamefield] = " & Forms!FormName!ComboBoxName & ";"

Docmd.runsql strSQL
```

This should do it.  Sorry, I'm two years late.